# laravel does't display Image in online hosted server

Tags: php, laravel-5

Images not displaying in webpage interface while it was fine and displayed in localhost.

I made an app with Laravel 5.2 and it was correct in localhost but after updaing it online we faced a very bad problem. All images which come from database aren't showing in webpage interface. I am storing images in Laravel root directory storage folder and image links to database table. Each image gets the exact stored image URL value but is not displaying properly. Also when I copied the image URL and pasted it in my browser it said :

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong

I am accessing images via this method

```
<img src="{{url::to('mvimage/'.$image->image) }}" />
```

I am accessing image via **route.php** by using this method

```
Route::get('mvimage/{file_name}', function($filename){
  $path = storage_path('app').'\mvimage\\'.$filename;
  $image = \File::get($path);
  $mime = \File::mimeType($path);
  return \Response::make($image, 200)->header('Content-Type', $mime);
});
```

Comment: Please check your error logs first and include any relevant error messages. There could be a number of reasons for a generic 500 error.

Comment: [2016-08-13 04:35:16] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException' with message 'File does not exist at path /home/techubaf/public_html/local/storage/app\teampics\2016-08-04-10-02-00am437.JPG' in /home/techubaf/public_html/local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:41
Stack trace:
this is the logger value

Comment: the problem is that if we want to access a photo publicly so we have to store it in public folder.
but i am storing photos in storage folder and laravel does't  allow me to access it.
actually the file exist in the position it points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the back slash..

Try with this

```
storage_path("app/mvimage/$filename");
```

Note :

- In your view you should access the facade with `URL` not `url`
- In your route file, you should be on the root namespace so no need for `\` before `File` and `Response`

Comment: OMG after many days only this helped me.!
thank you so much PeterPan666 you are great.

Comment: My pleasure dude ;)